# Matrix math syntax in wolfram alpha

Tags: matrices, derivatives, wolfram-alpha

I'm having trouble getting Wolfram Alpha to do my bidding with regard to matrix manipulations.  I am trying to take the derivative of the following matrix expression with respect to `m`, and was hoping WolframAlpha could be used:

`-(x-m)^T * E^-1 * (x-m)`

...However, I cannot discover how to input matrices as variables, and do not know what to use for the transpose operator.  (`^T` was used in this case.  `x` and `m` are vectors, `E` is a symmetric matrix.)

---

[Give a man a fish](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day._Teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime): How can this derivative be solved?

Teach a man to fish: How can I input such expressions into Wolfram Alpha?

If it helps, I know the solution should look something like (but may be off by some scalar constant):

`E^-1(x-m)`

Comment: x and m are 2x1, E is 2x2.

Comment: E is constant, not a function of m.

Comment: Don't we get a 1x1, since we have a (1x2)(2x2)(2x1)?

Comment: Also, why not use Mathics or Maxima or another free CAS? WA is great, but it makes stuff like this difficult as it does not support MMA commands outright.

Comment: I may have the dimensions of x and m incorrect, it could be that they are `1x2`.  I am terrible at getting the row/column order correct!

Comment: Try this on WA: -flatten({transpose(-(d/dm {m, m^2})+{x, y} )}).inverse({{a, b}, {b,c}}).((- d/dm ({m, m^2}))+{x, y})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want:

> $-$Transpose[x-m].Inverse[E].(x-m)

Although WolframAlpha might automatically think E is the number 2.71828....

Comment: This seems to be the way to enter matrices into WAM.  It also appears to think E is Euler's number as you predicted.  While I think *my* math w.r.t. the end result was incorrect, this was helpful in determining that.

Comment: So does anybody know how to input Matrix-valued symbolic variables such that alpha/mathematica DOES NOT incorrectly assume that they are scalars? This doesn't answer the underlying question so much as suggest it may not even be possible. Which is a surprising and disappointing.

Comment: Certain symbols are predefined by Mathematica—E is one of them—but most other capital letters are not (and you can give variable names like myMatrix as well). Operations like ^-1 and * are typed to assume scalars (or pointwise lists of scalars), while operations like Inverse and . are typed to work well with matrices. There is a [Mathematica and Wolfram Language stack exchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com), by the way!